Best Book - Understanding Investment Bank Operations
Could you please recommend Books to read for understanding Investment bank operations in Information Technology ( IT ) Point of view? like develop/support all system involved in FO/MO/BO systems in investment bank mainly for Derivatives ( Rate Products)
Trade Origination
Cash Flow
PV
realized cashflow vs   theoretical
settlement
documents
soon

Dated, but David Weiss, After the Trade Is Made: Processing Securities Transactions and Simmons Securities Operations: A Guide to Trade and Position Management are still good.
